# count (how to find all letters, and count them)

Tags: python, count

How to make = 2(there are two "the")

```
import re
text = "there are a lot of the cats"
o = re.findall("the", text)
print(o)


def text(word):
    count = 0
    for word in text:
        if "ou" in text:
            count += 1
    return count

print(count)

print(i)
```

this code should return 2 (because there are 2 "the")

Comment: You can get letter count with simply `len(text)` and to get every letter you can write a simple for loop `for letter in text: print(letter)`

Comment: Do you need to count letters or words?

Comment: isn't `print(len(o))` what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@chris is is right. You are successfully doing it on line 3 and 4, but line 4 returns it in an array `['the', 'the']`. In python you can get the 'length' of an array/list (how many things are in it) with `len(yourArrayHere)`.

So if you want to just see the count you can do:

```
print(len(o))
```

if you want to save it to a variable,
on line 5 just do this:

```
count = len(o)
```

everything after that is not needed

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get all words and count them here is the code:

```
text = input("Your text: ")
words_in_text = {}
for word in text.lower().split(" "):
    if word in words_in_text.keys():
        words_in_text[word] += 1
    else:
        words_in_text[word] = 1
```

To get a number of words simply use:

```
word_to_get = input("Which word to check: ")
print(words_in_text[word_to_get])
```

Here is a nice printed format for all words:

```
print("\nWord | Count")
for word, count in words_in_text.items():
    print(f"{word}: {count}")
```

Output:

```
Your text: My name is Echo Echo

Word | Count
my: 1
name: 1
is: 1
echo: 2
```